# Can't bind to 'lazyLoad' since it isn't a known property of 'img' tag in ionic3?

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

I have got above error after reload the page in ionic3 after apply lazy Loading on images ?
[image]

Steps I took:

Run Npm:
npm install ng2-lazyload-image --save`

Imported into my component:
import { LazyLoadImageDirective } from 'ng2-lazyload-image';

In my template:

In above template userProduct.ImageCollection is array of dynamic image that is get from the Fire-store but i got above error after load page.
Maybe there’s something I’m overlooking, but I can’t seem to see what it is.

```js
import { BrowserModule }                            from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule, enableProdMode }   from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader }         from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { LazyLoadImageModule }                      from 'ng2-lazyload-image';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
  MyApp,
  ImageSlider
],
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  LazyLoadImageModule,
  IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
  IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
  TranslateModule.forRoot({
    loader     : {
      provide    : TranslateLoader,
      useFactory : (createTranslateLoader),
      deps       : [HttpClient]
    }
  })
],
bootstrap: [IonicApp],
entryComponents: [
  MyApp,
  ImageSlider,
],
providers: [
  StatusBar,
  SplashScreen,
  Clipboard,
  {provide: ErrorHandler , useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
  Network
]
})
export class AppModule {}
enableProdMode();

export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
 return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

```html
 <img [defaultImage]="assets/imgs/product_defaultImg.png" [lazyLoad]="userProduct.ImageCollection[0].url" [offset]="offset">
```

Comment: Hi I am also facing the same issue. Can you please tell how did you fix the issue?

Comment: @neetu: hi neetu,not fixed it i have replace with normal loader on a image and set loader after response is not received.

Comment: Thank you for replying but I was able to fix it by moving the LazyLoadImageModule to my sub-modules from app module.

Comment: @neetu: its ok neetu what happend if you have move LazyLoadImageModule to my sub-modules?

Comment: In my case I had multiple sub-modules which I created apart from the default app module. So for me the fix was to import LazyLoadImageModule in my sub-module instead of app module which was in a higher hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks neetu for this useful information.tell me thing can you integrate PayPal in ionic3?